# How to SUM Only One Time Per UniqueId in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two tables that look roughly like this:

Table A

```
DocumentId (*is unique) DocumentDate
1                       2016-01-01
2                       2016-01-01
3                       2016-02-01
4                       2016-03-01
```

and Table B

```
ContractId SnapshotTimeId NetFinanced
1          20160231       300
1          20160331       300
1          20160431       300
2          20160231       450
2          20160331       450
2          20160431       450
3          20160331       500
3          20160431       500
4          20160431       150
```

I would like the final table to look something like this:

```
DocumentDate NetFinanced
2016-01-01   750
2016-02-01   500
2016-03-01   150
```

I have tried the following and it doesn't work:

```
SELECT A.DocumentDate, SUM(B.NetFinanced)
 FROM A
 JOIN B on B.ContractId=A.DocumentId
GROUP BY A.DocumentDate
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: You should read about `GROUP BY`.

Comment: is it a datetime or a date field ?

Comment: How the output will be that ? can you please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use distinct

```
SELECT  A.DocumentDate,
        SUM(B.NetFinanced)
FROM    A
        JOIN (SELECT    DISTINCT
                        ContractId,
                        NetFinanced
              FROM      B
             ) B ON B.ContractId = A.DocumentId
GROUP BY A.DocumentDate
```

the result of this will be different if the `NetFinanced` amount changes per `SnapshotTimeId`

if you want the most recent NetFinanced amount, you can use Row_number() to order the values.

```
SELECT  A.DocumentDate,
        SUM(B.NetFinanced)
FROM    A
        JOIN (SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ContractId ORDER BY SnapshotTimeId DESC) Rn,
                        ContractId,
                        NetFinanced
              FROM      B
             ) B ON B.ContractId = A.DocumentId AND B.Rn = 1
GROUP BY A.DocumentDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate values for `NetFinanced` in TableB, of course the results won't give you what you want. You need to join TableA with the unique values (I assume) of `ContractId` and `NetFinanced` columns from TableB:

```
SELECT A.DocumentDate,
       SUM(B.NetFinanced) NetFinanced
FROM dbo.TableA A
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ContractId, NetFinanced
            FROM dbo.TableB) B
    ON A.DocumentId = B.ContractId
GROUP BY A.DocumentDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
SELECT A.DocumentDate, SUM(B.NetFinanced)
FROM A
JOIN (SELECT MAX(ContractId) ContractId, MAX(SnapshotTimeId)SnapshotTimeId,
             MAX(NetFinanced)NetFinanced
      FROM B GROUP BY ContractId) B ON B.ContractId = A.DocumentId
GROUP BY A.DocumentDate
```